# How to mirror the RAW image in Android java code?

Tags: android, mirror, rawimage

I have got the RAW fingerprint image but need to mirror it for comparing it with another image.
The original Raw image data is shown below:

```
public void onUpImageSuccess(byte[] data) {
                Log.i("whw", "up image data.length="+data.length);
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                        data.length);
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageMirror.getInstance().MirrorImage(image,1);

                fingerprintImage
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}
```

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Already shared the code, the data is the image data byte[].